# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter not triggered

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use a `ContainerRequestFilter` to enforce some authentication on a Tomcat based Jersey application. I followed [this document](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-http-basic-auth-decoder/).
Problem : the filter is never triggered

The filter class :

```
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
        throws IOException {

        // MY AUTHENTICATION CODE GOES HERE

    }
```

The web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="debate-rest"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>rest</display-name>
   <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hck.debate.rest.security.AuthFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>  
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
      <param-value>com.hck.debate.rest.controller</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>  
        <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>      
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, I didn't get that the `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` init param needs to reference not only service classes (API endpoints) but ALL the classes including filters.

Now it works :

```
<init-param>  
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
  <param-value>com.hck.debate.rest.controller;com.hck.debate.rest.security</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.hck.debate.rest.security.AuthFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Your above code is working as it is with TomCat, maybe it's different with Glas Fish

Comment: The default behavior is to scan recursively, so you can also just use the single base package `com.hck.debate.rest`

Comment: Also note that `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters` and `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` are useless. These are Jersey 1.x properties. They have no impact on Jersey 2.x

Comment: Also note that by default, the package scanning is recursive. So instead of listing multiple packages, just declare a base package, like `com.hck.debate.rest`, and it will recursively scan all sub-packages.

Comment: And just an FYI, the scanning is to pick up classes annotated with `@Provider` and `@Path`, so you need to make sure to also have the `@Provider` annotation.

Answer (score 23):

I also had to add the **@Provider** JAX-RS annotation to my filters.
This makes the filter discoverable during JAX-RS scanning phase.

```
@Provider
public class MyAppFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    // filter logic
}
```

Comment: Same here without the annotation nothing happened

Comment: is it "@Provider" really necessary ?

Comment: Yes, I just had to add the @Provider annotation. Package scanning was already set up correctly

Answer (score 5):

Some hints:

1. Make sure you're using JAX-RS version 2.17.
2. Make sure you're using the right imports in your filter:

   - `import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;`
   - `import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;`
3. Add the `@Provider` annotation

Comment: is it "@Provider" really necessary ?

Comment: Yes, it annotates the component as a provider of something. It is used to extend the base JAX-RS functionality.

Answer (score 4):

We were missing the below call in our ResourceConfig implementation class:

```
register(CorrelationIdFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

The minimum requirements to work filters with jersey:

- add @Provider annotation to filter class
- the namespace of filter class has to be included in 'jersey.config.server.provider.packages' init-param

Any other settings aren't required (e.g. 'com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters' init-param or ResourceConfig)

Comment: is it "@Provider" really necessary ?

Comment: yes, it is. Jersey will load only the marked classes from the specified namespace

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for JAX-RS 2 , jersey and the below annotation fixed it

```
 @PreMatching
```

Comment: But that changes semantics! Adding this method **solely** influences **when** the filter is invoked. I seriously doubt that this *changes* the configuration of anything!

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `@Provider` annotation (which did not work in my case), you can register your `ContainerRequestFilter` manually with your `JerseyServletFactory`:

```
JerseyServletFactory jerseyServletFactory = new JerseyServletFactory(config);
HttpServlet myServiceServlet = jerseyServletFactory.create(myResource);

// Register your ContainerRequestFilter like this
jerseyServletFactory.addRequestFilter(new MyFilter());

httpServer.register(myServiceServlet, "/api");
httpServer.start();
```

Comment: and where is this piece of code supposed to be placed?

Comment: @jon During initialization. I've place my code between the creation and the start of the `JettyHttpServer`, with the other stuff that needs to get initialized on start (Datasources, Resources, DAOs, etc.)

Comment: I did the same, now i want to call destroy (for some custom cleanup task) of servlet. I am not able to get the reference back of this filter to call destroy in shutdown event.

Answer (score 0):

If you were stuck like me, note that TomEE 1.7.X uses JAX-RS 1.1, which does not include ContainerRequestFilter.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having this problem in MULE ESB.
Remember to register path with:

```
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
   <component doc:name="rest component">
     <spring-object bean="endpoit"/>
   </component>
   <jersey:package packageName="path @Provider-s"/>
</jersey:resources >
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of javax.ws.rs, i used com.sun.jersey and it worked

`import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest`

Dropwizard users need to do this

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig()
           .getContainerRequestFilters()
           .add(filter);
```

Comment: And thereby creating code that relies on packages you shouldnt rely on.