# How to handle CORS using JAX-RS with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, cors

I'm developing a java script client application, in server-side I need to handle CORS, all the services I had written in JAX-RS with JERSEY.
My code:

```
@CrossOriginResourceSharing(allowAllOrigins = true)
@GET
@Path("/readOthersCalendar")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response readOthersCalendar(String dataJson) throws Exception {  
     //my code. Edited by gimbal2 to fix formatting
     return Response.status(status).entity(jsonResponse).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
}
```

As of now, i'm getting error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.”

Please assist me with this.

Thanks & Regards
Buddha Puneeth

Comment: Just FYI I was using jax-rs jersey 2 and I needed to allow all requests for my RestApi.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter , The answer by **Krizka**
helped solve my problem really easily, as I configured the web.xml in my tomcat directory (apache tomcat 8). Was using angular 6 to make requests to my api.

Answer (score 190):

> **Note: Make sure to read the UPDATE at the bottom. The original answer includes a "lazy" implementation of the CORS filter**

With Jersey, to handle CORS, you can just use a [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). The `ContainerResponseFilter` for Jersey 1.x and 2.x are a bit different. Since you haven't mentioned which version you're using, I'll post both. Make sure you use the correct one.

### Jersey 2.x

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
            ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "CSRF-Token, X-Requested-By, Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

If you use package scanning to discover providers and resources, the `@Provider` annotation should take care of the configuration for you. If not, then you will need to explicitly register it with the `ResourceConfig` or the `Application` subclass.

Sample code to explicitly register filter with the `ResourceConfig`:

```
final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(new CORSFilter());
final final URI uri = ...;
final HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, resourceConfig);
```

> For Jersey 2.x, if you are having problems registering this filter, here are a couple resources that might help

> - [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](https://blog.dejavu.sk/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/)
> - [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)

### Jersey 1.x

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request,
            ContainerResponse response) {

        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "CSRF-Token, X-Requested-By, Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");

        return response;
    }
}
```

web.xml configuration, you can use

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.yourpackage.CORSFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or `ResourceConfig` you can do

```
resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new CORSFilter());
```

Or package scanning with the `@Provider` annotation.

---

### EDIT

Please note that the above example can be improved. You will need to know more about how CORS works. Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). For one, you will get the headers for all responses. This may not be desirable. You may just need to handle the preflight (or OPTIONS). If you want to see a better implemented CORS filter, you can check out the source code for the [RESTeasy `CorsFilter`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/d6fc3ea41014e88d4c296c7d985df956923886dc/resteasy-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.java)

---

### UPDATE

So I decided to add a more correct implementation. The above implementation is lazy and adds all the CORS headers to all requests. The other mistake is that being that it is only a *response* filter, the request is still processes. This means that when the preflight request comes in, which is an OPTIONS request, there will be no OPTIONS method implemented, so we will get a 405 response, which is incorrect.

Here's how it *should* work. So there are two types of CORS requests: simple requests and [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). For a simple request, the browser will send the actual request and add the `Origin` request header. The browser expects for the response to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, saying that the origin from the `Origin` header is allowed. In order for it to be considered a "simple request", it must meet the following criteria:

- **Be one of the following method:**

  - GET
  - HEAD
  - POST
- **Apart from headers automatically set by the browser, the request may only contain the following *manually* set headers:**

  - `Accept`
  - `Accept-Language`
  - `Content-Language`
  - `Content-Type`
  - `DPR`
  - `Save-Data`
  - `Viewport-Width`
  - `Width`
- **The only allowed values for the `Content-Type` header are:**

  - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `multipart/form-data`
  - `text/plain`

If the request doesn't meet all of these three criteria, a Preflight request is made. This is an OPTIONS request that is made to the server, *prior* to the actual request being made. It will contain different `Access-Control-XX-XX` headers, and the server should respond to those headers with its own CORS response headers. Here are the matching headers:

| REQUEST HEADER | RESPONSE HEADER |
| --- | --- |
| Origin | Access-Control-Allow-Origin |
| Access-Control-Request-Headers | Access-Control-Allow-Headers |
| Access-Control-Request-Method | Access-Control-Allow-Methods |
| XHR.withCredentials | Access-Control-Allow-Credentials |

- With the `Origin` request header, the value will be the origin server domain, and the response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be either this same address or `*` to specify that all origins are allowed.
- If the client tries to manually set any headers not in the above list, then the browser will set the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header, with the value being a list of all the headers the client is trying to set. The server should respond back with a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header, with the value being a list of headers it allows.
- The browser will also set the `Access-Control-Request-Method` request header, with the value being the HTTP method of the request. The server should respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header, with the value being a list of the methods it allows.
- If the client uses the `XHR.withCredentials`, then the server should respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header, with a value of `true`. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

So with all that said, here is a better implementation. Even though this is *better* than the above implementation, it is still inferior to the [RESTEasy one](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/d6fc3ea41014e88d4c296c7d985df956923886dc/resteasy-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.java) I linked to, as this implementation still allows all origins. But this filter does a better job of adhering to the CORS spec than the above filter which just adds the CORS response headers to all request. Note that you may also need to modify the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to match the headers that your application will allow; you may want o either add or remove some headers from the list in this example.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    /**
     * Method for ContainerRequestFilter.
     */
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {

        // If it's a preflight request, we abort the request with
        // a 200 status, and the CORS headers are added in the
        // response filter method below.
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A preflight request is an OPTIONS request
     * with an Origin header.
     */
    private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null
                && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
    }

    /**
     * Method for ContainerResponseFilter.
     */
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response)
            throws IOException {

        // if there is no Origin header, then it is not a
        // cross origin request. We don't do anything.
        if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
            return;
        }

        // If it is a preflight request, then we add all
        // the CORS headers here.
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                // Whatever other non-standard/safe headers (see list above) 
                // you want the client to be able to send to the server,
                // put it in this list. And remove the ones you don't want.
                "X-Requested-With, Authorization, " +
                "Accept-Version, Content-MD5, CSRF-Token, Content-Type");
        }

        // Cross origin requests can be either simple requests
        // or preflight request. We need to add this header
        // to both type of requests. Only preflight requests
        // need the previously added headers.
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

To learn more about CORS, I suggest reading the MDN docs on [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: How can I get an instance of `ResourceConfig`??

Comment: where should i put this class?

Comment: For some reason if there is an exception, CORS filter is not processed and I can't see the response! No fun to debug.

Comment: Just mentioning that http://stackoverflow.com/a/17345463/3757139 says, you have to register/add the filter class to your loaded classes of the jersey application. This helped me to get this working.

Comment: This also worked for me.  It is a bit annoying since CORS does not really confer any security but at least this makes it relatively painless.

Comment: I would like to know what library or libraries I should add to my java web app  to get it works: Actually I have added jaxrs-ri-2.0.jar. Sorry I am learning and I have tried for some hours. Thanks.

Comment: You need to have this import    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

Comment: For those wondering, you need the Maven dependency `jersey-server` in order to run the Jersey 1.19 code in this answer. See: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet/1.19

Comment: Thank you Paul Samsotha for sharing the complete solution, especially the update ! This is only solution, specifically the checking of pre-fetch header and `PreMatching` annotation that worked for me. And no other imports, but JAX-RS !

Comment: _The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are [...]_ That's a dangerous oversimplification. For more details, see the MDN Web Docs about CORS.

Answer (score 10):

Remove annotation "`@CrossOriginResourceSharing(allowAllOrigins = true)`"

Then Return Response like below:

```
return Response.ok()
               .entity(jsonResponse)
               .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
               .build();
```

But the `jsonResponse` should replace with a POJO Object!

Comment: This will only work for "simple" cors request, not preflight requests. See [the update in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435) to learn the difference.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer might be strictly correct, but misleading. The missing part is that you can mix filters from different sources together. Even thought Jersey might not provide CORS filter (not a fact I checked but I trust the other answer on that), you can use [tomcat's own CORS filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

I am using it successfully with Jersey. I have my own implementation of Basic Authentication filter, for example, together with CORS. Best of all, CORS filter is configured in web XML, not in code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was able to use it and configure the embedded tomcat with a replacement web.xml that included the CORS filter

Comment: Hey @DarkStar1, can you please post your configuration here. I need yo use it for embedded tomcat.

Comment: @skr It's been a long time ago now but [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460739/107301) is at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

peeskillet's answer is correct. But I get this error when refresh the web page (it is working only on first load):

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So instead of using add method to add headers for response, I using put method. This is my class

```
public class MCORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_VALUE = "*";

    private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
    private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_VALUE = "true";

    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS_VALUE = "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept";

    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS_VALUE = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD";

    public static final String[] ALL_HEADERs = {
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS
    };
    public static final String[] ALL_HEADER_VALUEs = {
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_VALUE,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_VALUE,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS_VALUE,
            ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS_VALUE
    };
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ALL_HEADERs.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Object> value = new ArrayList<>();
            value.add(ALL_HEADER_VALUEs[i]);
            response.getHttpHeaders().put(ALL_HEADERs[i], value); //using put method
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And add this class to init-param in web.xml

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.yourpackage.MCORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this for my project I used [Micheal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33427/michael) answer and arrived at this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>run-embedded</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <port>${maven.tomcat.port}</port>
                    <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                    <contextFile>${project.basedir}/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
                    <!--enable CORS for development purposes only. The web.xml file specified is a copy of
                        the auto generated web.xml with the additional CORS filter added -->
                    <tomcatWebXml>${maven.tomcat.web-xml.file}</tomcatWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The CORS filter being the basic example filter from [the tomcat site.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) 
**Edit**:
The **maven.tomcat.web-xml.file** variable is a pom defined property for the project and it contains the path to the web.xml file (located within my project)

Answer (score 0):

for multiple origin domains:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;


@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {

        final String domain = generateAllowOrigin(requestContext);

        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", domain);
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }

    private static String generateAllowOrigin(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        String caller = requestContext.getHeaderString("Origin");
        final String domain;
        if (caller != null && caller.contains("localhost:4141")) {
            domain = "http://localhost:4141";
        } else {
            domain = "https://example.com";
        }
        return domain;
    }
}
```