# jersey rest Application not deploying with shared library jax-rs 2.0 in weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, weblogic12c

I have a jersey rest application. I have used jersey 2.x classes including http request interceptors. however my weblogic 12.1.3 server has jersey 1.8. i deployed a jax-rs 2.0 shared library from [this link](https://github.com/georgeyanev/weblogic-jax-rs) in the server and referenced it in my weblogic.xml file. But when deploying it, it says There was a failure when processing annotations for application.

below are the error logs. what I'm I missing here?

```
<Sep 8, 2015 2:31:05 PM EAT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a    

    failure when processing annotations for application /home/martin/Dev/wls1213/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/upload/web-1.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at 

weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:275)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Sep 8, 2015 2:31:06 PM EAT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "19063043237576" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:275)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Sep 8, 2015 2:31:06 PM EAT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "web-1".> 
<Sep 8, 2015 2:31:06 PM EAT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:275)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Sep 8, 2015 2:31:06 PM EAT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:275)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:1804)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:764)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
```

below is my weblogic.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <context-root>/web</context-root>

  <session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>coherence-web</persistent-store-type>
  </session-descriptor> 

  <library-ref>
      <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
      <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
  </library-ref>

  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>


    </prefer-application-packages>
    <prefer-application-resources>
      <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>



    </prefer-application-resources>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The major 2 means Jersey has incompatibilities with version 1.  I wouldn't expect it to be backwards compatible.  I suppose you'll have to migrate or keep working in version 1.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using 1.x but problem is I have http interceptors which are absolutely crucial. would you be having a way of using interceptors in 1.x because when I add my url filter class with the annotation @provider in 1.x its not registered hence i cant intercept my requests.

Comment: I've never used Jersey 1.  Maybe you can accomplish something like it with javax.servlet.Filter?

Comment: @martinkimani See the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435) for how to register the filter in Jersey 1.x.