# Can't get a response at CORS request

Tags: web-services, rest, google-chrome-extension, jersey, cors

I have the following **Javascript code** to make a XMLHttpRequest to a server:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  return xhr;
}


function makeCorsRequest(word) {

    var url = "https://localhost:8080/Method/Dictionary/" + word;

    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var responseText = xhr.responseText;
        document.querySelector("#bar").innerHTML = responseText;
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        document.querySelector("#bar").innerHTML = 'Connection not allowed';
    };

    xhr.send();
}

makeCorsRequest("word");
```

At the server, I've got a REST structure (written using Jersey) similiar to:

```
@Path("/Dictionary")
public class Main{

public Definition returnDefinition(String word){

    Definition definition = new Definition();
    try{

    ...//play with Definition object
    return definition;
    }


    catch(IOException IOE){
        ...
        return definition;
    }

}


@Path("{word}") 
@GET 
@Produces("text/xml ; charset=UTF-8")                   //"Definition" is already set as a XMLRoot element
public Definition main (@PathParam("word") String word){
    return returnDefinition(word);
}

}
```

I try to make this request in two environments:

**First environment**: The JS code is inside a normal web page. In this case, I receive the following error after trying to make the request:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/Method/Dictionary/word. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Second environment**: The JS code is inside a content script (that is itself inside a chrome extension). In this case, after about 30s of trying to make the request, I receive this:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

How to proceed?

EDIT: I've added a command to print something at the console in the beginning of the server method. And it is not printed. So, the requests are not reaching the server.

Comment: Q: Does your browser support CORS (i.e. is it something *NEWER* than IE8)?  If so, it sounds like server configuration.  Please refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is trying to help!

@paulsm4 yes, It's the newer version of Chrome!

Comment: @wOxxOm When I said "Inside a normal page", I was trying to say that it is inside a normal HTML file, that I open with the browser...in the second case, this same code is inside a content-script : )

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your extension code - CORS is bypassed and the request is sent. Something is, however, wrong with your server. Check firewall settings, by the way.

Comment: @Xan Disabling the firewall showed no results. What could it be? I've not made much more at my Glassfish server than I showed here...

Comment: Well, _something_'s going wrong on the server side. Check/make logs. See if connections actually reach and what's going wrong.

Comment: The server was reached at one of my tests, but not at the other ones...and there is nothing weird in the log files. Everything is strange here.

Comment: Try [adding cors support on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28065963/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet didn't work too : (

Answer (score 0):

`Origin 'null'` happens if you are running the page as a file in the browser, using the `file://` protocol, rather than set it up in a local webserver and access it using `http://`.

Comment: Yep, testing on `file://` pages is always a bad idea unless this is the intended goal (which is almost never the case).

Comment: Ok, that is right (though I'm really trying to guess why it does not work anyway), but what about the second scenario?

Comment: No idea about that one sorry :(

Comment: `null` origin is normal for Chrome Extension code. However, Chrome Extensions can override CORS (which is demonstrated by the fact that request is _sent_). The problem is at the server side.

Comment: @vtortola no problems : )