# How to enable CORS in jersey server on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

Should the cors be enabled for tomcat in eclipse or web.xml

I enabled jar plugins and set them with web.xml but doesnt work

Comment: [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435) for an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working config :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

     <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <!-- add the headers here, that you want to read from REQUEST-->
        <param-value>Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <!-- add the headers here, that you want to WRITE in the response-->
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```