# Adding headers for Cross origin REST calls JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, http, cross-domain

I need cross origin REST call support for my APIs. Currently I have something like this.

```
@OPTIONS
public Response options() {
     return Response.ok()
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
                .build();
 }

@GET
@Path("/algorithms")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getAllAlgorithms() {
    List<MLAlgorithm> mlAlgorithms = MLCoreServiceValueHolder.getInstance().getAlgorithms();
    return Response.ok(mlAlgorithms).build();
}
```

I used a Rest client[1] for firefox to test API calls. When I do an OPTIONS call to the "`/api/configs`" API , and check the Response headers, I see only the following.

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 12:17:39 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
```

The first two headers are not set in the response header. I need cross origin support for all APIs in the class. How do I implement this, and what is the issue in the current implementation.

[1] https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

Comment: If that is what you see then none of the three headers are set. This looks like an interpreted version of the headers to me, as in the "access-control-allow-methods" header is transformed into the output "allow: get". Did you try to do the actual API call?

Comment: I used CURL also. same Output

Comment: You used CURL to do what :/ Minimal responses don't help.

Comment: This was my curl call for the API "curl -X options "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -v https://localhost:9443/api/configs -k" and i got the same response headers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add CORS support in a resource method you should use a filter instead. The problem with the resource method tactic, is that you will need to have the same method for *every* endpoint location. If a request is made to `/api/config`, then that endpoint must also have an OPTIONS method to handle the preflight. Same with all other endpoints. So best to just put it in a filter that can handle *all* requests.

You can see an example (for JAX-RS 2.0 and Jersey 1.x) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435)