# Java Jersey 1.8, adding CORS Filter does not work

Tags: javascript, java, jersey, cors

I'm trying to add a CORS-Filter to my Jersey 1.8 WebService.

```
    @ApplicationPath("/")
    public class RESTConfig extends Application {

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {                
            Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(CORSFilter.class);
            set.add(super.getClass());
            return super.getClasses(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }    
    }
```

and this is my CORSFilter from here():

```
    @Provider
    public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
        @Override
        public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request,
                ContainerResponse response) {

            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");

            return response;
        }
    }
```

I still get CORS Error from my Javascript-WebApp. 
Looking at the network traffic, no CORS header has been sent. What am I missing here?

Comment: the CORS filter is from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey

Comment: Too lazy to test, but what happens if you add it to override of `Set<Object> getSingletons()`, instead of `getClasses()`. Secondly `super.getClasses()` returns nothing. You should be simply returning the set.

Comment: definitely. was a typo! thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RESTConfig` is incorrect

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RESTConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(CORSFilter.class);

        // wrong
        //set.add(super.getClass());
        //return super.getClasses();

        // corrected
       set.addAll(super.getClasses());
       return set;
    }    
}
```

additionally if you override the `getClasses()` method you should add in it not only the filters but also all of your REST resources

```java
       set.add(MyHelloWorldResource.class);
       set.add(AnotherResource.class);
```

As an alternative you can extend the Jerseys `ResourceConfig` class in which case you can specify the whole package to be scanned for resources and filters.

```java
public class RESTConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public RESTConfig() {
        // scan the whole package and register all appropriate classes
        packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
        // register single class
        register(CORSFilter.class);
    }
}
```

For more information refer to [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Comment: thanks. this is the answer. if you have time and have an idea what the successing error is trying to tell me, be my guest :-)  

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

Comment: @user3601578 When you have an empty `Application` subclass (or return empty sets from getClasses() and getSingletons()), it automatically triggers scanning for classes with `@Path` and `@Provider`. Once you override one of the above mentioned methods and return a _non-empty_ set, it cancels out the scanning. So if the scanning was the method you were relying on previously, then you just cancelled it by overriding getClasses. My guess is you were overriding it do register the CORSFilter. Does it not get automatically registered when you use the scanning facility?

Comment: Thank u! alright. thats interesting. the other things in my web services are scanned properly then .. '@'Path before GET, POST etc., '@'JsonIgnore etc. 

What do you mean "scanning facility"? Where can I see what classes have been scanned already? I'm using Netbeans 8 if that helps ...

Comment: @user3601578 what @peeskillet is trying to say is that if you leave the extended `Application` class empty then Jersey should automatically scan your project and register all classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider`. I don't know if that true or not, have not tried this approach. From what I remember during the server startup Jersey should print to logs all the components that were registered

Comment: thank u all. for even though i learned a lot about jersey 1, it did not work that way. eventually, i end up simply adding this tomcat 8 valid filter to my web.xml 

     <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

thank u all. even though i learned a lot about jersey 1, it did not work that way. eventually, i ended up simply adding this tomcat 8 valid filter to my web.xml

```
    <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```