# Failed HTTP post request because of CORS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, cors, preflight

I do not manage to get my application running. I was reading about this the whole day, tried a bunch of stuff, but in the end nothing did work. In the last attempt I tried this [link](http://georgi-naumov.blogspot.ca/2014/02/angularjs-http-cors-and-http.html). I have the java back end as a RESTful web service without any additional framework like Jersey or RESTeasy, just pure java. There I have my login POST method:

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@Produces(value = "application/json")
public Response login() {

    AccountAuthentificator authentificator = AccountAuthentificator.getInstance();
    Status status = Response.Status.OK;

    String credentialValue = getHeaderValue(AccountAuthentificator.AUTH_CREDENTIALS);
    if (credentialValue == null) {
        status = Response.Status.FORBIDDEN;
        return WebServiceUtil.createResponse(status, "Missing account credentials in header.");
    }

    try {
        LoginResponse res = authentificator.login(credentialValue);
        return WebServiceUtil.createResponse(status, res);
    } catch (AccessControlException e) {
        status = Response.Status.FORBIDDEN;
        return WebServiceUtil.createResponse(status,
                "User does not exist. Please verify your user name and password.");
    }
}
```

The WebServiceUtil.createResponse method basically adds the necessary headers as you can see here:

```
public static Response createResponse(Status status, Object responseContent) {

    ResponseBuilder resBuilder = Response.status(status.getStatusCode());

    resBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    resBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    resBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

    resBuilder.allow("OPTIONS");

    resBuilder.entity(getJSONAsString(responseContent));

    return resBuilder.build();
}
```

I also saw people used another approach. It was with filters, like this [example](http://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/). I was also wondering if my implementation differs from this and where exactly is the preflight defined - in my implementation it is the .allow("OPTIONS") which does that, but you can correct me of I am wrong.

And then I have my web application where I call this POST method. I am using AngularJS for this. In my AuthenticateController controller I have the Login method, which is called on submit in the login form. The implementation looks like this:

```
function Login(username, password) {
        // CreateLoginHeader creates the authorization token through the login values username and password
        var authdata = CreateLoginHeader(username, password);
        var config = {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers:  { 'Authorization': authdata }
        };
        $http.post('http://XXXX', config).then(SuccessLogin, ErrorLogin);
    }
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here? Through the chrome developer tools I can see I get the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'placeholder-server-URL'. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'placeholder-client-URL' is therefore not allowed access.".

Should I be adding those two header values on the client side, when calling my back end:

- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Headers

Comment: So why are you making a cross domain call? The CORS headers has nothing to do with the clientside, the server would need to add them.

Comment: 'RESTful web service without any additional framework like Jersey or RESTeasy' - are you sure? see: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jax-rs/info

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I use javax: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> in my maven pom.xml file. And yeah, I also thought from what I was reading that the CORS header has to be implemented only on the server side @epascarello .It just happen that I followed another example and added those values programatically. But as far as I learned, they should be already created through the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Options request is not handled by `login`, so `createResponse` is not called.

Have a look at: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/supporting_cors_in_jax_rs (you should implement a `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`, see [How to handle CORS using JAX-RS with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey))

Another possibility for your code here (but not if you develop a 'real' application): add `@javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS` to your method like you did with `@javax.ws.rs.POST`.

Comment: OK, I tried this way and I was sticking to the tutorial [here](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1781/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-cors-on-rest-how-to-make-rest-apis-accessible-from-a-different-domain/). The only thing I did not do is changed the web.xml file like he did. I am extending the Application class and adding there my class with all the defined post/get methods. I also use the logger for the filters and it seems the filters are not called on the requests and responses. Any idea why is that the case?

Comment: Basically this is my Application class:
`@ApplicationPath("/api/v1/brain")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
 
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
  Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(StudyManagerService.class);
        return s;
    }

}`

Comment: Try to register the filters ("providers") the same way like your StudyManagerService.

Comment: That change did the job. I added my two filter classes:

`s.add(StudyManagerService.class);
        s.add(RESTRequestFilter.class);
        s.add(RESTResponseFilter.class);`

It seems I have an exception in the front end now, but at least I got one step further. Thanks @meiko

Comment: You are welcome, maybe you could mark an answer as correct ;)