# $http Cross domain access issue exists in header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jersey

A request is sent through Angularjs $http with JSON data to my REST service. When the response is returned, required headers are set as following,

```
Response.ok()
.entity(emp)
.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
.allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

But when I send a post request without data,

```
$http.post('localhost:8000/employer/register')
```

it is successful. With data, it fails.

```
$http({method: 'post', url:serverUrl, data:{name:'abc'}, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'} });
```

This is my Rest service

```
@Path("/register")
public class EmpService{

@Get
@Path("test")
@Produces
public String test(){
return "works";
}

@Post
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addEmp(Emp emp){

return Response.ok()
.entity(emp)
.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
.allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

Browser console is as following.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/employer/register (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).  
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/employer/register (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

UPDATE: I found that service is not invoked as no Sys.out.println gives any logs. 
 Anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: confused response is returned require headers set???? confusing because request is sent with or without headers

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad. I updated the question with the header values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the headers inside the resource method. Why? The preflight is an OPTIONS request, which is the "pre"-request to get the access control headers. And you don't have an OPTIONS method. The browser will not call the `@POST` method to get the access control headers. For this reason, you should be [using a filter instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435), and set the headers *there*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and guidance. The pointed answer solved my problem. Many Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be sending a header not allowed by the server.

Try this:

```
headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, otherCustomHeader");
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio. But I found that, even my service is not invoked with data is passed. Without data, it is success.

Comment: You could show the signature of the method on the server?

Comment: I updated the question with the service class. I added a test rest service method : GET . When I call it, it works. Only problem is the POST method with data. If no data, then it is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.May be your api route of server not allowed headers data that may be caused problem

```
$http.post(url:serverUrl, data:{name:'abc'}  } );
```

Comment: Thanks Wasiq. still it is same. :(

Comment: I updated my question (see below of question) with browser console. Also I found that service is also not invoked .