# jquery: ajax get request not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call following url using get request.

http://localhost:8080/abc/employees

When I opened above url in browser, I am getting following response.

> *[{"firstName":"Hari Krishna","id":1,"lastName":"Gurram","permAddrees":{"area":"Marthali","city":"Bangalore","country":"India","state":"Karnataka"},"tempAddrees":{"area":"Electronic
>   City","city":"Bangalore","country":"India","state":"Karnataka"}},{"firstName":"PTR","id":2,"lastName":"PTR","permAddrees":{"area":"Bharath
>   Nagar","city":"Hyderabad","country":"India","state":"Andhra
>   Pradesh"},"tempAddrees":{"area":"BTM
>   Layout","city":"Bangalore","country":"India","state":"Karnataka"}}]*

Following is my jquery snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <h1>Click the below button to see the AJAX response</h1>
        <input type="submit" value="click here" id="button1" />

        <div id="placeHolder">

        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

            jq(document).ready(function(){
                jq("#button1").click(function(){
                    alert("Hello");
                    jq.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/employees", function(data, status){
                        alert(data + "" + status);
                        jq("#placeHolder").html(response);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, it is showing first alert box 'alert("Hello");', but the alert box in call back function is not executed. Can any one help me to figure out the issue with my code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You have `response` in your call, but you're not defining it anywhere - you should be getting an error in console. You're actually making call to `/abc/employees/1` in the screenshot. By any chance is your output different based upon what header the request uses (json / html)? Also - please not use `alert` but `console.log` - `alert` by default stringifies everything, so it's useless in debugging (you still should have a string in Chrome Response tab irregardless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Safari allows it and chrome does not allow (CROSS ORIGIN REQUEST SHARING - CORS).

**An experiment :**

Let's execute a request from this [html file](http://pastebin.com/pdzScdzt) to **"www.google.com"** from our **"localhost"**.

**What happens in chrome ?**

In chrome , CORS (CROSS ORIGIN REQUEST SHARING) is not allowed and hence it stops you in doing that.

[image: Chrome gives the error as show below for http://www.google.com]

[Read about it here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/1270865)

**What happens in Safari ?**

Safari allows this behaviour and hence you get this response from
**http://www.google.com**

> Proof [image: I have added url as http://www.google.com, and hence this response comes]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access localhost for your file which is not part of locahost

**Two things can be done:**

1. Make the file a part of your localhost web application
2. Make proper CORS settings, for instance is you are using JERSEY use the following.

[How to handle CORS using JAX-RS with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey)