# CORS with basic HTTP Authentication

Tags: java, jersey, cors, jax-rs

I'm having some problems using basic HTTP Authentication with CORS: We have a node express web server (UI), calling a HTTP API from a Java Dropwizard (Jersey) server, running on the same host.

The API is protected with HTTP basic authentication, and I''ve implemented the following filter on my Jersey server (taken from this post: [How to handle CORS using JAX-RS with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey)):

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
                                         ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

However, when I try to load the web UI, my console gives me the following output:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/intraday/parameters. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:9000’)
```

I'm unable to make sense of this error. Clearly the origin is the same (http://localhost:9000), so I don't get why it doesn't match.

I've also made sure that any preflighted OPTIONS requests are answered with HTTP code 200.

Comment: maybe this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey

Comment: @sascha10000 The link you provided is the same post I already linked to in my question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't really see that this was a link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description in the question, it sounds like the Java Dropwizard (Jersey) server is running on `http://localhost:9000` and the node express web server (UI) is running at another origin.

Regardless, you must set the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in the `CORSFilter` code on the Jersey server to the origin of the frontend JavaScript code that’s making the request (apparently the node server). So if that’s, e.g., `http://localhost:12345`, then:

```
response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:12345");
```

It anyway must be something other than `http://localhost:9000`, because there’s no way your browser would emit that *“disallows reading the remote resource at `http://localhost:9000/…`”* error message if the frontend JavaScript code the request is getting sent from is being served from `http://localhost:9000`—since in that case it wouldn’t be a cross-origin request and your browser wouldn’t be blocking access to the response.