# axios request to put jersy service does not work

Tags: ajax, jersey, axios

I have a very frustrating problem. I have a my put servive in jersy and I call it via axios. Here is my code for jersy:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update(@PathParam("id") int id, String jsonRequest) {
    return new UpdateController().updateUser(id, jsonRequest);
}
```

Here is how I call it in the front end:

```
axios.put(putURL, newUserPreferences)
        .then(response => {
        .
        .
```

So if I call it with the avobe put request I get the following error code:

```
Failed to load puturl...: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3003' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Can anyone help why it is happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28065963/2587435

Comment: @peeskillet thanks so I added cores in the web.xml and all methods works except put. When I use put I get Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3003' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: Here is what I added in my web.xml: <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: @peeskillet please see my update

Comment: You need more configuration. Please read the docs https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: @peeskillet Right your answer is right. Thanx. The issue was configuration