# Issue with angular 5 + jersey

Tags: java, api, jersey, jax-rs, angular5

I have an issue trying to send an HTTP POST request with Angular 5 and getting it with Jersey 2.26, but for some reason the header params are null.

Do you have any idea what is happening?

I have attached some screenshots of both angular and jersey.

#### [Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLrZ.png)

[image: Angular]

#### [Jersey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJj7p.png)

[image: Jersey]

Note: I could not add a new comment (I don't know why) so I publish the solution.

Thanks for your suggestions, I solved the issue adding id_token, use_cases as allowed parameters in Access-Control-Allow-Header tag inside standalone-full.xml (wildfly 11) and filtering only POST, GET, UPDATE, PUT methods in a custom ContainerRequestFilter, as follow:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) throws IOException {
    if (!requestCtx.getRequest().getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) {

        String path = requestCtx.getUriInfo().getPath();
```

Comment: Is this a `Java` or `Javascript` problem?

Comment: You have a CORS problem. What you're seeing is the preflight OPTIONS request. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey/28067653#28067653

Comment: Also you're not even use Jersey, though you think you might be. I see the class `ResteasyHttpHeaders` class in your debugger, which means your using RESTEasy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I solved the issue adding id_token, use_cases as allowed parameters in Access-Control-Allow-Header tag inside standalone-full.xml (wildfly 11) and filtering only POST, GET, UPDATE, PUT methods in a custom ContainerRequestFilter