# exception in parsing the request after pre-flight request using jersey

Tags: rest, web-services, cors, jersey-2.0

1. We have created the CORS filter as follows:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

       @Override
       public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
           ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {

           // TODO: Allow only from *our* Web front 
           response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
               "origin, content-type, accept,x-request-id, x-api-key, x-api-secret, authorization");
           response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
           response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
               "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
       }
   }
   ```
2. We have created a REST resource

   Following is the code:

   ```
   @Path("MyResource")
   @POST
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String MyResource(TestInput input) {
       return input.getName();
   }
   ```
3. The class TestInput is as follows:

   ```
   public class TestInput {
       private String name;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
   }
   ```
4. **It produces the result as expected from Postman. But if we hit the resource from http://resttesttest.com/ or any client, following error occurs:**

   > javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 117 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
   >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   >
   > **Root Cause**
   >
   > javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 117 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)
   >       org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.unexpectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:601)
   >       org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:418)
   >       org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$NoneContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:413)
   >       org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:363)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonbRiParser.next(JsonbRiParser.java:140)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.getRootEvent(Unmarshaller.java:66)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:56)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
   >       org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
   >       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
   >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
5. **preflight request is handled by returning if cors header is present.**

Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with your ContainerResquestFilter. What you need to do only update your **TestInput** class and add the following annotation on it.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestInput {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```