# How to Deploy Angular app with Proxy Settings

Tags: angular

I have a proxy config file which has API(web service) link to target to make calls to our database. This proxy config is working fine locally using **npm start** .

Now I Need to deploy this app to our production windows server on IIS. 
I used **ng build** and **ng build --prod**  looks like this is not generating build with proxy setting. 
I need help that How I can generate a build with proxy setting so that I can deploy it to prod server.

Api is deployed on some other domain  and this angular app will be deployed on some other domain.

Thanks

Comment: As I know, not sure if it is possible or not! We have published the API and webapp in a single site to avoid this!

Comment: And where you going to deploy this? Cloud? Windows server?

Comment: going to deploy is on windows server

Comment: Ok, IIS server?

Comment: For most production environments, avoiding proxy on the Angular app side is essential. In my case, I just configured Nginx to act as a proxy.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583665/10660059
If you are working with Docker or Nginx this answer might be helpful for you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The proxy config file is for the local development web server. The main reason you use it is so you can avoid cross domain requests when developing the Angular app and the api on your local machine without having to allow cross domain requests in the api.

When you release to production there is no support for the proxy config file. You will be releasing to your production web server.

If your api is hosted under the same domain then there is no need for proxying requests as they are not cross domain and if the api is on another domain you will need to allow cross domain request in the api.

Answer (score 2):

### To deploy an **Angular 8** application to production

You can use the **environments** feature, for example:

### For **Development**

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000/api",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
}
```

You set the backend baseURL in **environments/environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backend: {
    baseURL:"http://localhost:3000/api"
  }
};
```

In the **service** the **baseURL** is used:

```
  baseUrl: string = environment.backend.baseURL;

  getAll(): Observable<UsersResponse> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
     this.http.get<AccountsResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}` + '/users')
        .subscribe((result) => {
          const accountsResponse = result;
          observer.next(accountsResponse);
          observer.complete();
        });
    });
  }
```

For development the live serve is used:

```
$ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

The url for development:

```
http://localhost:4200/yourapp
```

The running serve will enable CORS and send the API calls to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1
```

### For **Deployment to production**

The command to build for **production**:

```
$ng build --prod --base-href=/yourapp/
```

The service will take the **baseURL** from prod environment configuration:

**environments/environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  backend: {
    baseURL:"http://example.com/api"
  }
};
```

So, by using different environments, you can configure different api urls.
Remember to enable CORS in your production web server, by default the browser does not allow to connect to a different domain than the one serving your Angular app.

Comment: Hi @daniel-mora I have a question for you.  What if you also need to deploy to other environments like RC, QA, Test etc?  And what if you had multiple of each, for instance 10 QA environments?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Don't use IIS Server.

You can create an application with node and express to serve your static files and to be your api server, which will call the right one (almost like a redirect)

What ng serve --proxy-config probably does is to run a node server with your application exposed as static and run api's according to your configuration redirecting (calling the server) to the server.

When we call an api from node server, there's no CORS because we don't have a hostname like an web application.

---

Option 2: With IIS and a node/express application## Heading ##

You can create an application and allow the CORS to your hostname. From this application you can expose a generic api and call the right api server.