# Not able to receive header parameter in ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, web-services, jersey-2.0

I'm creating web-services in Java with Jersey2.0. Everything works as expected when I execute request from **POSTMAN** but when I execute request from the client application I'm not able to receive header parameter. My client application is on JavaScript. Also, I've added the CORS allows origin request parameters in **ContainerResponseContext**.

The following shows my **ContainerResponseFilter** class where I add the CORS.

```
@Provider
class CORSFilter : ContainerResponseFilter {

    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext?, responseContext: ContainerResponseContext?) {
        responseContext?.apply {
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, authorization, accept, privatekey")
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
        }
    }
}
```

The **privatekey** is my header name for the request. Now here's my code for **ContainerRequestFilter**.

```
@Priority(AUTHENTICATION)
@Provider
class JsTokenFilterNeeded : JsBaseFilter(this::class.java.simpleName) {

    override fun filter(request: ContainerRequestContext?) {
        val path = request?.uriInfo?.path       
        val privateKeyHeaderValue = request?.getHeaderString("privatekey")
        println("private key -> $privateKeyHeaderValue")
    }
}
```

I'm always getting the null value in **privateKeyHeaderValue**. Both the containers are successfully registered in **ResourceConfig** class.

As of now, I'm getting no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource here's the log.

```
{host=[203.***.51.***:5555], connection=[keep-alive], access-control-request-method=[GET], origin=[http://localhost:38596], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36], access-control-request-headers=[privatekey], accept=[*/*], alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph=[AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.3], referer=[http://localhost:38596/], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.9]}
```

**Edit 1**
Here's my Js code for the client application.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'privatekey': privateKey
        },
        url: "http://***.124.**.76:5555/dcu/energy/"+active_import,
        data: {
            'dcu_id': '99220445',
            'tariff': 0
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

**Edit2**
I'm using ResourceConfig in order to register my Providers. Here's my ResourceConfig class.

```
class MyResourceConfig : ResourceConfig() {

    init {
        register(CORSFilter())
        register(JsTokenFilterNeeded())
    }
}
```

Comment: As you described, from postman everything works OK. Please share the client code in JS. In addition, I would recommend to print the entire request to log (or debug) and see what is missing.

Comment: I've already printed the log in the question at the end if you see and for Js code, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @AdiOhana added the JavaScript code.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey . are you using package scanning to discover providers and resources? If not, then you should explicitly register the CORSFilter

Comment: @AdiOhana I've already seen this link before posting my question and also I'm using the resource config in order to register my Providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that happened before the real request. The preflight request doesn't send any of the headers (the key header included). It only sends headers asking the server if the request is allowed. So when the preflight request reaches the filter, the token will not be there.

What you should do is make the CorsFilter implement both a `ContainerRequestFilter` *and* a `ContainerResponseFilter`. Make it a `@PreMatching` filter. That way it will be called before the token filter. In the *request* filter, check to see if it is a preflight request. If it is, then abort the request. This will cause the request to skip the rest of the request filters and go straight to the *response* filters. In the response filter side, you can add the CORS headers.

You should read [the UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435) in this post to get a better understanding of the flow of the CORS protocol and also see a better implementation of the CorsFilter that you can use that should work for your scenario.