# Post requisition failed

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, post, request

I'm trying to make a POST request, to convert and download a file to pdf, but I have this error:
documento.service.ts :

```
  download(documento: IDocumento) {
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + "api/download/", documento).subscribe((response) => {
      saveAs(response, documento.tituloDocumento + "." + "pdf");
    });
  }
```

DocumentResource

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void download(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody DocumentoDTO documentoDTO) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(documentoDTO.getPathorigdoc());
    response.setContentType("pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;" + documentoDTO.getTituloDocumento());
    response.getOutputStream().write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
}
```

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://autenticacao.campogrande.ms.gov.br/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=web_app&scope=openid%20offline_access%20profile%20email%20address%20phone%20roles%20web-origins%20jhipster&state=DooRYbdfmKCip2apn-NOTWQOqWBGkeh-AigMtoJVfcM%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/oidc' (redirected from 'http://localhost:9000/api/download/') from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
autenticacao.campogrande.ms.gov.br/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=web_app&scope=openid%20offline_access%20profile%20email%20address%20phone%20roles%20web-origins%20jhipster&state=DooRYbdfmKCip2apn-NOTWQOqWBGkeh-AigMtoJVfcM%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/oidc:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:6249 ERROR HttpErrorResponse
```

Comment: You need to set up CORS on your server to allow your app to make XHR requests

Comment: can you tell me where i do this?

Comment: On your API. I saw this question because it came up in my Angular feed. You should read up on CORS in SpringBoot while you don't have any answers here.

Comment: This seems like a good place to start https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what server are you using, but you need to modify the headers value in the service ( an example in java)

[How to handle CORS using JAX-RS with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey)

Answer (score 0):

Being able to solve, but you are not managing the download, I believe it is because or the answer is returning null, do I need to fix anything?

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/download")
public void download(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody DocumentoDTO documentoDTO) throws IOException {
    String caminho = "";

    caminho += "/arquivos/leisweb" + File.separator + documentoDTO.getPathorigdoc();

    File file = new File(caminho);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;" + documentoDTO.getTituloDocumento() + ".pdf");
    response.getOutputStream().write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
}

  download(documento: IDocumento) {
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + "api/download", documento).subscribe((response) => {
      saveAs(response, documento.tituloDocumento + "." + "pdf");
    });
  }
```

Return:  Exit: .web.rest.DocumentoResource.download() with result = null